# Does $d (f,\,g)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}\,dx$ induce a topological vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C$ be the vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. Define
$$
d (f,\,g)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}\,dx.
$$

Let $(C,\tau)$ be the topological space induced by $d$.

If $d$ induce a topological vector space, then

1. each single point is closed.
2. addition and multiplication is continuous under this metric.

I can prove (1) and addition is continuous since $d$ is translation invariant. But how to prove multiplication is continuous?

For each $t\in \mathbb C$, $f\in C$ and $r>0$, it suffices to prove there are $\delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2>0$, such that if
$$
|s-t|<\delta_1,\quad g\in B (f,\,\delta_2),
$$
one has
$$
sg\in B(tf,\,r).
$$

We have 
$$
d (sg,\,tf)\leq d (sg,\,sf)+d (sf,\,tf)
$$
and
$$
\int_0 ^{1}\frac{|sf-tf|}{1+|sf-tf|}\,dx\leq\frac{|s-t|M}{1+|s-t|M}<\frac{r}{2}
$$
if
$$
|s-t|<\frac{r}{(2-r)M},
$$
where $M$ an upper bound of $|f|$.

But how to modulate $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ to ensure $d (sg,\,sf)<\frac{r}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

It is a standard exercise in real analysis to show that $d(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$ if and only if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure, that is,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|(|f_{n}-f|\geq\epsilon)|=0
\end{align*}
for each $\epsilon>0$.

Now it suffices to show that, when $t_{n}\rightarrow t$ and $d(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$, then $d(t_{n}f_{n},tf)\rightarrow 0$.

So we are to show that $t_{n}f_{n}\rightarrow tf$ in measure.

Note that convergence in measure $\varphi_{n}\rightarrow\varphi$ is also equivalent to the following:

For any subsequence $(\varphi_{n_{k}})$ of $(\varphi_{n})$, there is a further subsequence $(\varphi_{n_{k_{l}}})$ of $(\varphi_{n_{k}})$ such that $\varphi_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow\varphi$ a.e.

Using this equivalent characterization of convergence in measure, the result follows.